# Posting html code with php fails at style attribute and spaces

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, post, ace-editor

I'm using [ACE Editor](http://ace.c9.io/) for a website which has been developed by Codeigniter framework. The problem is that after submitting the form, some tags attributes stripped.

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url( 'admin/slider/populateFile')?>">
<div id="e1" style="display: none;">
   <?php if(isset($sliderHTML)) { echo $sliderHTML; } ?>
</div>                         
<textarea class=" form-control" id="editorTextarea"  name="sliderHTML" type="text" rows='20' wrap="off">
    <?php if(isset($sliderHTML)) { echo $sliderHTML; } ?>
</textarea>                               
 <pre id="editor"></pre>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function populateFile()
{
    $sliderHTML = $this->input->post('sliderHTML');
    //echo $sliderHTML;
    $filePath = 'application/views/admin/slider/sliderHTML.txt';        
    write_file($filePath, $sliderHTML, 'w');        
    redirect('admin/slider', 'location');
}
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to write in the code editor:

```
<img class="ls-l" style="top:195px;left:50%;white-space:nowrap;" data-ls="offsetxin:0;delayin:1720;easingin:easeInOutQuart;scalexin:0.7;scaleyin:0.7;offsetxout:-800;durationout:1000;" src="http://localhost:8080/afa/application/views/images/upload/slider/4978d-s1.jpg" alt="">

 <p class="ls-l" style="top:150px;left:116px;font-weight: 300;height:40px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;font-size:30px;line-height:37px;color:#ffffff;background:#82d10c;border-radius:3px;white-space:nowrap;" data-ls="offsetxin:0;durationin:2000;delayin:1500;easingin:easeOutElastic;rotatexin:-90;transformoriginin:50% top 0;offsetxout:-200;durationout:1000;">
                FEATURES
 </p>
```

But, the output will be like:

```
<img class="ls-l"  data-ls="offsetxin:0;delayin:1720;easingin:easeInOutQuart;scalexin:0.7;scaleyin:0.7;offsetxout:-800;durationout:1000;" src="http://localhost:8080/afa/application/views/images/upload/slider/4978d-s1.jpg" alt="">
  <p class="ls-l"  300;height:40px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;font-size:30px;line-height:37px;color:#ffffff;background:#82d10c;border-radius:3px;white-space:nowrap;" data-ls="offsetxin:0;durationin:2000;delayin:1500;easingin:easeOutElastic;rotatexin:-90;transformoriginin:50% top 0;offsetxout:-200;durationout:1000;">
                FEATURES
  </p>
```

Notice that style attribute of `img` has been stripped, and this happens also for `<p>` but it stops on the space after `font-weight:`. I don't know why.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT:** Finally, I knew that this has nothing to do with the code editor. The problem was with xss_filtering in Codeigniter and [this answer works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14926324/1235037). :)

Comment: Looks to me like the editor is buggy. It seems like it's trying to parse your code, but failing. Maybe it doesn't allow embedded CSS and it's trying to get rid of it, but failing. Maybe it's trying to move the CSS into a stylesheet. I would just try adding extra spaces to trick it into accepting. You could also give the element an ID and put the CSS in a stylesheet.

Comment: Well, i tried to use just textarea without any editor and I used ckeditor (I wrote at the source), but this gave me the same result.

Comment: And, for this inline style, it must be inline, because I will use it in another place which needs it like this. :\

Comment: I shouldn't have called it the editor. The thing you submit your code to is what I'm referring to. To prevent XSS attacks, it may be trying to remove non-whitelisted attributes, but it's not removing them completely, so it's not doing a good job. Maybe you can take advantage of that by adding more spaces. Does it remove an empty style attribute? A style attribute with only one style inside? A style attribute with just a space? A style attribute listed as the first attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ace in particular (i like Wysihtml5), but I think they have something in common.

Wysihtml5 strips html (you can select which). It makes sure the html output is clean.

In short, it's a function and apparently style is not permitted. You should permit that (if it has the option to)

Comment: I searched for something like this in the [documentation](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor), but I don't find anything related to the situation here.

Comment: I've searched too, couldn't find it. But CI does not select what to send through and what to delete. As it is a common function in any good editor I will bet my left testicle on it. Keep searching or switch to alternative. It has to be there

Comment: You should think about posting another question: how to enable style tag is Ace editor

Answer (score 0):

You should escape value of `$sliderHTML` with `htmlspecialchars` before adding it to the document, otherwise it will create actual tags and break your page.

try putting `"</textarea><script>alert('all your passwords belong to us')</script>"` in place of `$sliderHTML`